# Page break: enumeration with headline

Tags: page-breaking, enumitem

In my document I created a new environment called `examples`. Basically it's an enumeration with the headline "Examples".

The idea is to get something like:

**Examples**

1. Example 1
2. Example 2
3. Example 3

The problem is that sometimes the headline "Examples" is on one page and the enumeration begins on the following page:

[image]

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\newenvironment{examples}
{%
    %\begin{samepage}
    \textbf{Examples} % HEADLINE
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=4em,label={\alph*)},labelsep=4em]
    \setlength{\itemsep}{1em}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}
{%
    \end{enumerate}
    %\end{samepage}
}

\begin{document}

    \blindtext[4]
    Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.

    \begin{examples}
    \item \blindtext[1]
    \item \blindtext[2]
    \end{examples}

\end{document}
```

I tried to use the `samepage`-environment, but this environment does what its name says: It doesn't break between the enumeration items:

[image]

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\newenvironment{examples}
{%
    \begin{samepage}
    \textbf{Examples} % HEADLINE
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=4em,label={\alph*)},labelsep=4em]
    \setlength{\itemsep}{1em}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}
{%
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{samepage}
}

\begin{document}

    \blindtext[2]

    \begin{examples}
    \item \blindtext[1]
    \item \blindtext[2]
    \end{examples}

\end{document}
```

So what I want is that after the headline "Examples" is no page break, but the items should break normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use beginpenalty:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\newenvironment{examples}
{%
 \par\medskip\noindent    
    \textbf{Examples} % HEADLINE
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=4em,label={\alph*)},labelsep=4em,beginpenalty=10000]
    \setlength{\itemsep}{1em}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}
{%
    \end{enumerate}
}

\begin{document}

    \blindtext[2]

    \begin{examples}
    \item \blindtext[1]
    \item \blindtext[2]
    \end{examples}

\end{document}
```

With a koma-class I would use \minisec to print the header:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\newenvironment{examples}
{%
    \minisec{Examples} % HEADLINE
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=4em,label={\alph*)},labelsep=4em]
    \setlength{\itemsep}{1em}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}
{%
    \end{enumerate}
}

\begin{document}

    \blindtext[2]

    \begin{examples}
    \item \blindtext[1]
    \item \blindtext[2]
    \end{examples}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually I use a koma-class. `\minisec{}` does the trick. Danke ;)